# Javascript object properties null outside of member functions

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a site I'm making with Google Maps integration. Below is some sample code showing layout and where I'm having issues, I think it's scope related but can't figure it out. the Maps API calls initMap() once it's loaded to anything using the API has to be performed within initMap, but I also need obj to be a global variable so it can be accessed and do things after initMap() has finished.

```
var obj = {};
var initMap = function() {
  obj = {
    "map": null,
    "locations": null,
    "refreshStuff": function() {
      // Do things to populate all the null values
      // i.e.
      obj.locations = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
      alert(/*message to show values are what they should be*/); // They are
      },
    "otherThings": "otherThings"
    };
  obj.refreshStuff();
  alert(/*message to check values are still what they should be*/); // They're null
  };
alert(/*message to check values are still what they should be*/); // They're null
```

Is there a reason that obj's null properties are reverting back to null once outside of the function that sets them?

**EDIT 1**

The member vairables aren't always reverting to null, they're reverting to whatever they're se to initially, I just am using null initially for all of them.

```
obj = {
  "location_ex1": null,
  "location_ex2": 0
  };
alert(obj.location_ex1); // null
alert(obj.location_ex1); // 0
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a full code snippet for one function that's not setting values correctly

```
obj = {
  // ...
  "userLocationFirstRun": true,
  "refreshUserLocation": function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        obj.userLocation.position = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        if (obj.userLocationFirstRun) {
          obj.userLocationFirstRun = false;
          obj.userLocation.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: obj.map,
            position: obj.userLocation.position,
            draggable: false,
            icon: { url: "/images/location_marker.png" }
            });
          }
        alert(JSON.stringify(obj.userLocation.position)); // <-- Correct coords
        }, function() {
          //Geolocation error - Service failed
          alert("Geolocation service failed");
          });
      }
    else {
      //Geolocation error - No geolocation ability
      alert("Geolocation service not available");
      }
    },
  "userLocation": {
    "marker": null,
    "position": null,
    }
  // ...
  };
obj.refreshUserLocation();
alert(JSON.stringify(obj.userLocation.position)); // <-- null
```

Comment: Does `refreshStuff` make any asynchronous function calls? It would be preferable if you gave a [mcve] instead of putting comments everywhere.

Comment: There is Ajax in there to load location data, however its not only things that are set through Ajax loaded data. I'm having items like user location coordinates which are loaded via HTML5 navigator are also reverting to null. So far any member variable being set from within a member function, however I may be setting it, is reverting to null.

Comment: I just tested it and they're not reverting to null per se, but reverting to the value set as default in the member variable declaration. i.e. "locations": null returns null and "locations": 0 retuens 0

Comment: Can you show some more of the code? Once you call `initMap()` all of the variables which get set by `refreshStuff` are showing up with non-null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you use `obj` inside of `refreshStuff`, its obj which is equal to {}, before `obj` is updated to have the refresh stuff function, if yous eee what I mean.

In fact I am right, proof:

https://jsfiddle.net/9szgwyru/

Comment: So if I'm following correctly, I have to create the layout for the entire object without setting the functions and then for the do obj.functionName = function(){} afterwards? Does it matter that you set obj.refreshStuff outside of initMap? Because I have to create them all within initMap() otherwise I don't have access to the Google Maps API.

Comment: Heres the deal, you set obj to a new object with a function that acts on object. However when you defined the function, obj was still the old object ({}) since youre in the middle of setting it to a new object. So the `obj` inside the refresh function is the old one rather than the one you are setting it to. Does that make sense?

Comment: Got it. Thank you, I just rearranged some of the code to test and that's it. Thank you @Hunter